Not able to load selected values in duallistboxes
I´m pretty new to using LWC in salesforce and have a very complex requirement. The requirement is based on 3 topics

3 dependent multi-select picklists
For some values in Box A there should also be a value selected in Box B
Selected values should be saved and if I open the LWC again the saved values should be filled in the dual listboxes automatically.

I already successfully implemented 1+2 and also can save the values without any issues but have problems fetching the saved data and filling the boxes.
Here you can find my code:
APEX
public with sharing class DualListboxController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account getAccountData(Id accountId) {
        // Query to fetch selected values from the account
        return [SELECT Media_Category_Text__c, Product_Category_Text__c, Product_name_text__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId LIMIT 1];
    }
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateAccountData(Id accountId, String mediaCategory, String productCategory, String productName) {
        // Update the account with selected values
        Account acc = [SELECT Id, Media_Category_Text__c, Product_Category_Text__c, Product_name_text__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId LIMIT 1];
        acc.Media_Category_Text__c = mediaCategory;
        acc.Product_Category_Text__c = productCategory;
        acc.Product_name_text__c = productName;
        update acc;
    }
}

HTML
<template>
    <lightning-card title="">
        <div class="container">
            <lightning-button label="Update" onclick={handleUpdate}></lightning-button>

            <!-- Conditionally render the dual list boxes -->
            <template if:true={showListBoxes}>
                <lightning-dual-listbox
                    name="firstList"
                    label="Media Category"
                    source-label="Available"
                    selected-label="Selected"
                    options={firstListOptions}
                    onchange={handleFirstListChange}
                    value={selectedFirstListValues}
                    class="dual-listbox"
                    required
                >
                </lightning-dual-listbox>

                <lightning-dual-listbox
                    name="secondList"
                    label="Product category"
                    source-label="Available"
                    selected-label="Selected"
                    options={secondListOptions}
                    onchange={handleSecondListChange}
                    value={selectedSecondListValues}
                    class="dual-listbox"
                >
                </lightning-dual-listbox>

                <lightning-dual-listbox
                    name="thirdList"
                    label="Product name"
                    source-label="Available"
                    selected-label="Selected"
                    options={thirdListOptions}
                    onchange={handleThirdListChange}
                    value={selectedThirdListValues}
                    class="dual-listbox"
                >
                </lightning-dual-listbox>

                <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={handleSave}></lightning-button>
            </template>

    </div>
</lightning-card>
</template>         

JS
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getAccountData from '@salesforce/apex/DualListboxController.getAccountData';
import updateAccountData from '@salesforce/apex/DualListboxController.updateAccountData';

export default class TripleDualListBox extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId; // Account ID

    @track firstListOptions = [
        { label: 'Audio', value: 'Audio' },
        { label: 'TV', value: 'TV' },
        { label: 'Print', value: 'Print' },
        { label: 'Digital', value: 'Digital' }
    ];
    @track secondListOptions = [];
    @track thirdListOptions = [];
    @track selectedFirstListValues = [];
    @track selectedSecondListValues = [];
    @track selectedThirdListValues = [];

    // State variable to show/hide the dual listboxes
    @track showListBoxes = false;

    allOptions = {
        Audio: [
            { label: 'Audio', value: 'Audio' }
        ],
        TV: [
            { label: 'TV', value: 'TV' }
        ],
        Print: [
            { label: 'Print', value: 'Print' }
        ],
        Digital: [
            { label: 'Digital TV', value: 'DigitalTV' },
            { label: 'Online video', value: 'OnlineVideo' },
            { label: 'Display', value: 'Display' },
            { label: 'Social', value: 'Social' }
        ]
    };

    allThirdListOptions = {
        Audio: [
            { label: 'Digital Audio', value: 'Digital Audio' },
            { label: 'Radio', value: 'Radio' }
        ],
        TV: [
            { label: 'Linear TV', value: 'Linear TV' }
        ],
        Print: [
            { label: 'Print', value: 'Print' },
            { label: 'OOH', value: 'OOH' }
        ],
        DigitalTV: [
            { label: 'Broadcast video', value: 'Broadcast video' },
            { label: 'TV Display', value: 'TV Display' }
        ],
        OnlineVideo: [
            { label: 'Instream video', value: 'Instream video' },
            { label: 'Interstitial ads', value: 'Interstitial ads' },
            { label: 'Accompanying ads', value: 'Accompanying ads' },
            { label: 'Outstream video', value: 'Outstream video' }
        ],
        Display: [
            { label: 'Digital display', value: 'Digital display' }
        ],
        Social: [
            { label: 'Social video', value: 'Social video' },
            { label: 'Social display', value: 'Social display' }
        ]
    };

    handleUpdate() {
        // Fetch stored values from Salesforce and update listboxes
        getAccountData({ accountId: this.recordId })
            .then(result => {
                // Log the entire result object to see the fetched data
                console.log('Fetched account data:', result);

                // Show list boxes after loading data
                this.showListBoxes = true;
    
                // Convert stored comma-separated strings into arrays
                this.selectedFirstListValues = result.Media_Category_text__c ? result.Media_Category_text__c.split(',') : [];
                this.selectedSecondListValues = result.Product_Category_text__c ? result.Product_Category_text__c.split(',') : [];
                this.selectedThirdListValues = result.Product_Name_text__c ? result.Product_Name_text__c.split(',') : [];
    
                // Log the converted arrays
                console.log('Selected First List Values:', this.selectedFirstListValues);
                console.log('Selected Second List Values:', this.selectedSecondListValues);
                console.log('Selected Third List Values:', this.selectedThirdListValues);
    
                // Initialize options for the second and third lists
                this.updateFirstListOptions();
                this.updateSecondListOptions();
                this.updateThirdListOptions();
    
                // Ensure selections are valid
                this.validateSelections();
    
                // Update the text fields initially
                this.updateTextFields();


            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error loading account data: ', error);
            });
    }

    validateSelections() {
        // Ensure that the current selections are still valid given the options available
        this.selectedSecondListValues = this.selectedSecondListValues.filter(value =>
            this.secondListOptions.some(option => option.value === value)
        );

        this.selectedThirdListValues = this.selectedThirdListValues.filter(value =>
            this.thirdListOptions.some(option => option.value === value)
        );
    }

    handleFirstListChange(event) {
        this.selectedFirstListValues = event.detail.value;
        this.updateSecondListOptions();

        // Automatically select related options in the second list based on the first list selection
        const autoSelectInSecondList = ['Audio', 'Print', 'TV'];

        this.selectedSecondListValues = this.selectedFirstListValues.filter(value =>
            autoSelectInSecondList.includes(value)
        );

        // Update the third list options based on the second list selection
        this.updateThirdListOptions();

        // Reset the selected third list values
        this.selectedThirdListValues = [];
    }

    handleSecondListChange(event) {
        this.selectedSecondListValues = event.detail.value;
        this.updateThirdListOptions();

        // Reset the selected third list values
        this.selectedThirdListValues = [];
    }

    handleThirdListChange(event) {
        this.selectedThirdListValues = event.detail.value;
    }

    handleSave() {
        // Save the selected values in the Account object
        updateAccountData({
            accountId: this.recordId,
            mediaCategory: this.selectedFirstListValues.join(','),
            productCategory: this.selectedSecondListValues.join(','),
            productName: this.selectedThirdListValues.join(',')
        })
        .then(() => {
            console.log('Account data saved successfully');

            // Update text fields and hide the list boxes
            this.updateTextFields();
            this.showListBoxes = false;
            window.location.reload();

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error saving account data: ', error);
        });
    }

    updateSecondListOptions() {
        this.secondListOptions = [];
        this.selectedFirstListValues.forEach(category => {
            if (this.allOptions[category]) {
                this.secondListOptions = [...this.secondListOptions, ...this.allOptions[category]];
            }
        });

        // Select values based on Product_Category_text__c field and automatic selection
        const autoSelectInSecondList = ['Audio', 'Print', 'TV'];
        this.selectedSecondListValues = this.selectedSecondListValues.concat(
            this.selectedFirstListValues.filter(value => autoSelectInSecondList.includes(value))
        ).filter((value, index, self) => 
            self.indexOf(value) === index && this.secondListOptions.some(option => option.value === value)
        );
    }

    updateThirdListOptions() {
        this.thirdListOptions = [];
        this.selectedSecondListValues.forEach(option => {
            if (this.allThirdListOptions[option]) {
                this.thirdListOptions = [...this.thirdListOptions, ...this.allThirdListOptions[option]];
            }
        });

        // Select values based on Product_Name_text__c field
        this.selectedThirdListValues = this.selectedThirdListValues.filter(value => 
            this.thirdListOptions.some(option => option.value === value)
        );
    }

    updateTextFields() {
        // Update text fields with the selected values
        this.mediaCategoryText = this.selectedFirstListValues.join(', ');
        this.productCategoryText = this.selectedSecondListValues.join(', ');
        this.productNameText = this.selectedThirdListValues.join(', ');
    }
}

Any idea where I made the mistake? Like I said, I'm pretty new and any help/comments would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks


Make sure the getAccountData method is correctly fetching the data from Salesforce. You can add some debug logs in your Apex method to verify this.
Ensure that the fetched data is correctly bound to the selectedFirstListValues, selectedSecondListValues, and selectedThirdListValues in your LWC. You can add some console logs to verify the data.
Ensure that the list options are updated after fetching the data. You might need to call updateSecondListOptions and updateThirdListOptions after setting the selected values.

